# Limit on number of List venues returned?

Tags: foursquare

I seem to be getting a limit of a max of 30 venues for any list that I am calling via the API, even if the response shows many more; for example, 'All of Epicurious’s Tips' shows a "count" value of 426 in the response, but only 30 venues actually show up in the "listItems":"items" array in the .json. It seems I was able to access all venues on a list a couple of weeks back, regardless of size. Is 30 venues the limit for a list response?

Comment: can you add more information such as the actual call you are making to the API (with the oauth token removed)? - it would help to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** actually, ignore the below answer (although it may help) this could be a pagination issue. Looking at the [docs for lists](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/lists/lists.html) it seems that endpoint supports pagination, so you can call with a parameter of `&limit=200` to get the first 200 results, then another call with `&limit=200&offset=200` to get the next 200 results and so on.

---

If you were able to access all the venues a couple of weeks ago, can you try adding a [version parameter](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/overview.html#versioning) to your api call to find out when it worked and when it stopped working?

i.e. - if you add a parameter `&v=20111101` to the end of your API call, you'll get the results that you would've got if you'd called the api on the 1st November 2011. This might help pin down the issue, or at least will allow you to retrieve the whole list for now until the issue is sorted.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the reply.The limit and offset works well. Looking back at my previous downoads, I notice that the limit of 200 has always been in place, but I think the default was to load up to 200 without specifying it as a parameter; now the default seems to be max 30.

Answer (score 1):

According documentation, the limit is 50
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

Answer (score -2):

If you are using the StackOverflow (JSON) API version 2.0 then this might be of help:
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging

Quoting from the link above:
Nearly all methods in the API accept the `page` and `pagesize` parameters for fetching specific pages of results from the API. `page` starts at and defaults to 1, `pagesize` can be any value between 0 and 100 and **defaults to 30**.

So the query should contain `&pagesize=100` where 100 is replaced with the number of items (pages) required.